# regex get decimal value from a string e.g 1.4em

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal, css

I have been scratching my head and searching around and i cannot seem to find another question quite like the problem i am having.

i have a variable e.g:

```
var style = ' font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.4em; ';
```

and i can quite easily extract the value of font-size using (and use this method for a lot of other values i need to retrive):

```
var match = /(?:^|\s)font-size\s*:\s*(\d+)px/i.exec( style );
fontsizetest = match && match[1];
console.log(fontsizetest);
```

but when i try to extract the value of the line height (with relative em sizing) i get all sort of problems (mainly due to the decimal place):

After playing around for quite a while this is the closest i can get to a solution:

```
var match = /(?:^|\s)line-height\s*:\s*(\d|\.|\d*)em/i.exec( style );
lineheighttest = match && match[1];
console.log(lineheighttest);
```

but this does not return my value of 1.4

Any ideas or advice of pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I am sure there is a simple explanation but i have just been looking at it for too long?

Many Thanks

Comment: That would be `parseFloat` -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Ybs/)

Comment: I would expect the number part to be something more like `"10.11em".match(/((\d+\.?)?\d+)em/);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're weak at regular expression syntax.

Try this:

```
var match = /(?:^|\s)line-height\s*:\s*((?:\d*\.)?\d+)em/i.exec( style );
```

This accepts numers like `2`, `.8` or `1.2`.

Comment: Thats great... that has solved my problem. thank you.

i am weak at regular expression syntax. but trying to improve

thanks again

Comment: @CharlieDavey You're welcome. Regular expression can be complex, I don't deny it. Experience helps. Try to understand what I've put in the capturing group.